# /usr/bin/ before /usr/local/bin/ while $PATH is correct

Tags: macos, terminal, path, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Zshell is not picking up the $PATH variable and still calls executables in `/usr/bin/` before ones in `/usr/local/bin/`. e.g. `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python`, while my $PATH variable (`echo $PATH`) is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.

I am using zshell and oh-my-zsh, in OS X default terminal, I've tried almost everything I could find, cleaned up .zshrc, nothing worked, it is a new computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `rehash` (same as `hash -r`) to update the shell's
internal hash table and see your change reflected.